# CKReferences not appearing in CloudKit dashboard

Tags: cloudkit, ckreference

Why am I not able to see references in the CloudKit dashboard?

I set up CKReferences like this:

```
let ouS = CKRecord(recordType: "OU")
let userR = CKReference(recordID: userRecordID, action: .None)
organizationUserS.setObject(userR, forKey:"user")

publicDatabase.saveRecord(organizationUserS, completionHandler: { ouS2, error in
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meantime, until today morning references panel appeared for that certain record on dashboard, it is an iOS8 beta side effect.

**Checking first the new Record Type what you started to use** and **then Default Zone**, afterwards you will able to force to plot reference panel.